# gz file corrupted while transfer

Tags: rsync, compression, redhat-enterprise-linux, gzip, gz

I have huge gz files generated in linux machines and everyday night there is a script running to move files to remote network storage which is also linux host with terabytes data. The problem is, I am not sure if it is happening during transfer or creation time, but in remote network storage there are gz files which are corrupted:

**unexpected end of file**

**invalid compressed data--format violated**

I am using rsync 3.0.6 for this and gzip version 1.5.

My question is, as gz files needed to transfer with binary mode (not ASCII), how can I specify it via rsync, or it is automatically set?

Also, can rsyslog version result this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that the key phrase is “I have huge gz files ***generated in*** Linux machines”.  Is it possible that your script is trying to transfer the files while they are still being created?

Comment: Thanks for reply, script is transferring files which have been created 3days before.